# Dynamically creating 'pretty' racetrack from list of coordinates

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, 2d

So I'm in the middle of creating a racing game for Android (but this problem is more generic than Java so I hope I've asked in the right place)...

For my game I am dynamically generating new maps for the user to 'race' and to allow them preview the track they want to race on beforehand I need to well, dynamically draw a preview image to represent a track.

My first solution was a simple list of cordinates for corners, using basic drawLine between them to give the user a preview of the map, as intended... However a 2D green line on the screen is bland and i'm just looking for tips to improve it. I tried, altering line colors slightly too...

Perhaps this is best shown with an example:

[image]

Above shows a bad example of a preview of a generated 'race track' its a windy track with a sharp turn and then finishes.

This is a terrible design and looks bland, and will ruin immersion in my game...

So (apart from generating better tracks!) how can I **pretty-ify** the preview of a track to make it look appealing? I know this is a VERY generic question and more about DESIGN than programming, but I was just wondering if someone had an insight or tips: *I mean I know I could animate it/preview ghostrace on the track, but i'm first looking for obvious solutions before making a whole project out of previewing a track.*

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, you're right: this isn't really a code problem at all. Is there a visual design Stack Exchange somewhere?

Comment: well no, but for game development. I think there are some people over there that can help more than we can: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/
software devs aren't really known for their good graphic designs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Bezier Curves?  They are a way of defining attractive curves with fairly few points, and most graphics systems are quick to draw them.  Don't worry too much about the math, just get the concept that the points define the general direction of the curves, maybe play with them in a graphics program, and then program with them.  I think if you follow a pretty simple rule, don't let the points get too close to each other, you should get decent curves.

Then as far as design goes . . . I'm not really great at that, but I would start with making a thicker line and then drawing a thinner line within that.  Try out different color combinations.  Maybe make the thin line in the center dashed and yellow or white, like a road stripe.